# Issues with POSTGIS ST_DISTANCE function and results

Tags: postgresql, postgis

## Hi I have a bit of issues with postgis and calculations.

Using ST_DISTANCE causes a bit of confusion:

```
SELECT st_distance(
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(16.0420,45.8250), 4326),
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(16.1675,45.8344), 4326));
```

returns 0.12585153952177025 as an result.

The result seems a bit odd as on a simple visible checking those points are quite far away and result 
should be in meters.

For instance :

```
select st_distance(
  'POINT(15.651955 73.712769 )'::geography,
  'POINT(14.806993 74.131451 )'::geography) AS d;
```

returns 53536.74349675 which seems to work properly.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[`st_distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) returns a distance in the unit of the used coordinate system. For 4326, the unit is `degree`, so the distance is in degrees (which is meaningless).

As you have done, you can cast to geography first, which returns a result in meters. You can also use [`ST_DistanceSpheroid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html) to get a distance in meters, or you can use a suitable coordinate system whose unit is in meters.